# Magento 2 Localhost mail issue

Tags: magento2, email-templates, send-mail

I am trying to send custom template using below function in localhost.

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_custom_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($email_to)
            ->getTransport()->sendMessage();
```

But mail is not going so what changes i need to do in localhost to make it working or is there any other way.

Can any one please guide me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question? So we get more idea, how you're sending emails.

Comment: Added my code, but i think this code is not working due to some setting of localhost.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code

Comment: Have you added GMAIL SMTP in localhost?

Comment: I have added below module and done all setting and also send test mail. https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Comment: I have tried to print something in sendMessage() function in its interceptor but its not going into that function.

Comment: If there is any other way to do this then suggest me that.

Comment: You got 2 test emails when you sent test emails from backend?

Comment: Where you've created this template ? **send_email_custom_template**

Comment: I have added this in email_templates.xml and after that created .html file under "view/email" folder.

Comment: Getting two test email from backend.

Comment: Please click on chat link, we will discuss there

Comment: Thanks @KishanSavaliya for all your help. The mail is working now.

Comment: You're welcome Buddy :)